# make a right border on beamer

Tags: latex, beamer, tikz

put a border on the right in a beamer

Hello,

After seeing new slides in beamer that were more correct, I was interested in transforming the power point template that I use into a latex.

[image: image template ppt]

But here's the problem, I tried to make the border on the right with this code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


% Tikz package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{236, 223, 212}
\definecolor{border}{RGB}{230, 204, 177}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MyBackground}


% Remove navigation bar
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \
    \fill[color=border] (\paperwidth-20pt,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\myTitlebis{titre}{sous titre}
    
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

and it gives me this [image: my result]

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the build-in `sidebar` theme of beamer as a starting point:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


% Tikz package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{236, 223, 212}
\definecolor{border}{RGB}{230, 204, 177}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MyBackground}



% Remove navigation bar
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\useoutertheme[right,width=1cm,height=0cm]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=border}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]